# current song getting paused when routed to another page in react JS, how to keep it playing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am trying to implement a music app in reactjs where users can perform all the operations like Spotify, as I was working on it I got stuck here [the song getting paused as soon as I go from one route to another.]

I want to implement something like : as we go from one route to another, the song should keep playing in the background. I read many articles and blogs and also watched YouTube videos but none of them worked for me. Can someone tell me how I can make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

refer this sandbox, I tried to solve the above problem, Just like Header component is used in react JS.

Refer this link, code will explain:

[Sandbox For Audio + Router React](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-dawn-h2rnx?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: you have used a nice approach brother but still there is something more I am looking for , is there any way to connect with you ? By the way, I appreciate your response and help.

Comment: Sure, https://www.linkedin.com/in/siddharth-varangaonkar-9b4a3a150/

Comment: I sent you request. brother